# How to test properly a parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I'm having problems trying to test a Component which displays and handles the interactions between 2 children.
I know I should try to test the functionalities that the user can trigger by interacting with the component. But in this case i can't write tests preventing the repetition of tests between parent and children.

Assume this case: a `ParentComponent` which renders two children.
First child is a `FilterComponent` which receives as props a handler function for the submit event.
Second child is a `TableComponent` which receives as props a list display a table.

My `ParentComponent` is something like this:

```js
const TableWithFilters = ({list} : {list: Array<any>}) => {
   const [filter, setFilter] = useState({name: ""});
   
   const handleFiltersSubmit = useCallback((filters: any) => {
        setFilters(filters);
   }, [filters])

   const filterPredicate = (obj: any) => {
       return obj.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filters.name.toUpperCase()) !== -1;
   }

   const filteredList = useMemo(() => {
        return filters.name ? list.filter(filterPredicate) : list;
   }, [filters.name, list.length]);

   return (
      <>
         <FilterComponent onFiltersSubmit={handleFiltersSubmit} />
         <TableComponent list={list} />
      </>
   )

}
```

I wrote the tests for both `Children` components. For instance, in the `FilterComponent` I have a form which renders a input field and a button to submit, so i wrote the test to check if input and button are rendered and a test to check if the function passed in the props is actually called when clicking on submit.

Now to me seem a bit redundant to write a similar test for the `ParentComponent`, but honestly I don't know what kind of expectations I should set which are not already checked in ChildrenComponents.

Is this a hint of bad design of the hierarchy or the separation of concerns?

Answer (score 0):

I'd test whether your `filterPredicate` works correctly. It should filter out what you are expecting to be filtered out and other way around. E.g. change the case of filters array, etc.

Let's say other engineer refactors this function. You need to be sure it still works as expected.

Comment: Should i spy filterPredicate function with jest? I saw on some articles that the state of component and how it changes shouldn't be the target of a test and a developer should focus on the consequences of the change (E.g. updates on the render of ui). So in my case i should check that table rows change when i submit the form. But as i said this overlaps some tests already written in the 2 children.

Comment: I personally extract all unrelated to the component functions to a "util" file. It is easier to test it and makes code a bit lighter. 
If you don't wish to extract it from your component then test is probably going to be:
1. render your component; 2.simulate submit 3.parse the props of resulting component